# Move folders using file path in excel file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

my goal is to move specified folders and their contents outof an existing location into a new folder path labeled "Archive". There are about 1000 folders out of 2000 I need moved to this new location. I have a .xlsx file that contains the file paths of each folder that needs moving, listed in column A of the Excel worksheet. I would like my macro to look at the Excel file, read the folder path, move that folder and its contents to a new destination. Repeat through the Excel list until it reaches a blank, then it's considered "Done!"

Here is the code I have found so far (see below). This code will move one folder from ***one*** path to another path. I need to enhance this to read each path from my Excel file; I just don't know what that part of the command should look like.

Code and any notes with the code are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
Sub Move_Rename_Folder()
    'This example move the folder from FromPath to ToPath.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    FromPath = "Q:\Corporate-Shares\...\Test folder 1" '<< Change
    ToPath = "Q:\Corporate-Shares\...\Test Archive Folder" '<< Change
    'Note: It is not possible to use a folder that exist in ToPath

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    If fso.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If fso.FolderExists(ToPath) = True Then
        MsgBox ToPath & " exist, not possible to move to a existing folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    fso.MoveFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "The folder is moved from " & FromPath & " to " & ToPath
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please test this code in a test folder before working with your original files. Create copies or dummy files, any failure can damage your existing files....**

First, separate this move function taking the name and destination of the path:

```
Sub Move_Rename_Folder(FromPath as string, ToPath as string)


    'to do these two lines, go to tools, references and add Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime 
    'it's a lot easier to work like this
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = new FileSystemObject

    'you don't need to set paths anymore, they come as the arguments for this sub

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    If fso.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If fso.FolderExists(ToPath) = True Then
        MsgBox ToPath & " exist, not possible to move to a existing folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    fso.MoveFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "The folder is moved from " & FromPath & " to " & ToPath
 End Sub
```

Then, create a main Sub to run over the column "B" (from path) and Column "C" (to path), for instance:

```
Sub MainSub()
     Dim CurrentFrom as Range, CurrentTo as Range

     'get B2, assuming your B1 is a header, not a folder
     Set CurrentFrom = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("yoursheetname").Range("B2")
     'get C2, assuming your C1 is a header
     Set CurrentTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("yoursheetname").Range("C2")

     'get the actual values - paths - from cells
     Dim ToPath as string, FromPath as string
     ToPath = CurrentTo.value     
     FromPath = CurrentFrom.Value

     'loop while your current frompath is not empty
     Do while FromPath <> ""
         'calls the move function from frompath to topath
         Call Move_Rename_Folder(FromPath, ToPath)

         'offsets the cells one row down
         Set CurrentFrom = CurrentFrom.Offset(1,0)
         Set CurrentTo = CurrentTo.Offset(1,0)

         'gets the values of the new cells
         FromPath = CurrentFrom.Value
         ToPath = CurrentTo.Value
     Loop
End Sub
```